# Recuperate a form field in an array

Tags: arrays, angular, forms

This is the form I have :

```
chartform = this.formbuilder({
 id:[],
 typeOfchart : [],
 indicators:[]
 })
```

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="chartform">
 <input formControlName = "id" >put an id </input>
 <input formControlName = "typeOfchart" >type of the chart </input>
 <select  formControlName = "indicators">
   <option  *ngFor="let indicator of metricindicators" value="indicator">{{indicator}}</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

I want to recuperate the value of "indicators" in an array so tried ths in the component.ts:

```
let indexes = chartform(['indicators']).value
console.log("indexes",indexes.length) // when I input for example "performance" in the field 
 "indicators" the console display "indexes 11" while it must display "indexes 1" it show me the 
  number of caracters not the number of elements in the array
```

I tried another method :

```
let indexes : any = []
indexes.push(chartform(['indicators']).value)
console.log("indexes",indexes.length) // here it gives me "indexes 1" when I input"performance" but 
when I put "performance,currency" in the field "indicators" the
console display "indexes 1" while it must display "indexes 2"
```

Can anyone help me how to fix this please

Answer (score 0):

Your "indicators" it's an unique value, not an array. To get the value you need use

```
this.chartform.value.indicators
//or
this.chartform.get('indicators').value
```

NOTE, you can use ngModel also to change the value of the formControl directy(*)

```
<select [ngModel]="chartform.get('indicators').value?chartform.get('indicators').value[0]:null"
            (ngModelChange)="chartform.get('indicators').setValue([$event])"
            [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}">

       <option  *ngFor="let indicator of metricindicators" [value]="indicator">
           {{indicator}}
       </option>
</select>
```

NOTE2: see that it's `[value]="indicator"`, you forget the `[` `]`

(*)yes, you can use [ngModel] inside a ReactiveForm always this input is used in "standalone", that's, it's independienty of the formGroup

Comment: Thanks for answering but my problem is not to recuperate the value of indicators my problem is how to put it in an array like I mentionned below

Comment: `let indexes : any = [this.chartform.get('indicators').value]` or using [ngModel] standalone